# Retrieve rows from a table which has multiple dependencies

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g DB and I need to retrieve row id 2 from Table A, as it has two rows on Table B where the Table D's status is true TRUE.
Row id 1 from Table A cannot be retrieve, as it has two rows but out-of those two rows one of the row's Table D's status is FALSE.

How to select above rows from a single sql select query?

**Table A**

```
Id  | FName      | LName
-----------------------------
1   | Jhone      | A
2   | Alice      | B
3   | Bob        | C
```

**Table B**

```
A.Id  | order_id    
--------------
1     | 1     
1     | 2     
2     | 3
2     | 1
```

**Table C**

```
B.order_id  | order_type    
--------------
1           | X     
2           | Y     
3           | Z
```

**Table D**

```
C.order_type  | order_status    
--------------
X           | TRUE     
Y           | FALSE     
Z           | TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns all `a` where there is no false `d`, which is what I think you want:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b join
                       c
                       on b.order_id = c.order_id join
                       d
                       on c.order_type = d.order_type
                  where b.id = a.id and
                        d.order_status = 'false'
                 );
```